# Occasional missing polygons drawing a sky sphere (at far plane)

Tags: directx, hlsl, visual-glitch

I am drawing a sky sphere as the background for a 3D view.  Occasionally, when navigating around the view, there is a visual glitch that pops in:

[image: Black or missing polygon in the middle of blue sky]

*Example of the glitch: a black shape where rendering has apparently not placed fragments onscreen*

- Black is the colour the device is cleared to at the beginning of each frame.
- The shape of the black area is different each time, and is sometimes visibly many polygons.  They are always centred around a common point, usually close to the centre of the screen
- Repainting without changing the navigation (eye position and look) doesn't make the glitch vanish, i.e. it does seem to be dependent on specific navigation
- The moment navigation is changed, even an infinitesimal amount, it vanishes and the sky draws solidly.  The vast majority of painting is correct.  Eventually as you move around you will spot another glitch.
- Changing the radius of the sphere (to, say, 0.9 of the near/far plane distance) doesn't seem to remove the glitches
- Changing Z-buffer writing or the Z test in the effect technique makes no difference
- There is no DX debug output (when running with the debug version of the runtime, maximum validation, and shader debugging enabled.)

What could be the cause of these glitches?

I am using Direct3D9 (June 2010 SDK), shaders compiled to SM3, and the glitch has been observed on ATI cards and VMWare Fusion virtual cards on Windows 7 and XP.

### Example code

The sky is being drawn as a sphere (error-checking etc removed the the below code):

**To create**

```
const float fRadius = GetScene().GetFarPlane() - GetScene().GetNearPlane()*2;
D3DXCreateSphere(GetScene().GetDevicePtr(), fRadius, 64, 64, &m_poSphere, 0);
```

Changing the radius doesn't seem to affect the presence of glitches.

**Vertex shader**

```
OutputVS ColorVS(float3 posL : POSITION0, float4 c : COLOR0) {
   OutputVS outVS = (OutputVS)0;
   // Center around the eye
   posL += g_vecEyePos; 
   // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
   outVS.posH = mul(float4(posL, 1.0f), g_mWorldViewProj).xyzw; // Always on the far plane
```

**Pixel shader**

Does't matter, even one outputting a solid colour will glitch:

```
float4 ColorPS(float altitude : COLOR0) : COLOR {
   return float4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

[image: Same image, with a solid-colour pixel shader]

*The same image with a solid-colour pixel shader, to be certain the PS isn't the cause of the problem*

**Technique**

```
technique BackgroundTech {
    pass P0     {
        // Specify the vertex and pixel shader associated with this pass.
        vertexShader = compile vs_3_0 ColorVS();
        pixelShader  = compile ps_3_0 ColorPS();

        // sky is visible from inside - cull mode is inverted (clockwise)
        CullMode = CW;
    }
}
```

I tried adding in state settings affecting the depth, such as `ZWriteEnabled = false`.  None made any difference.

Comment: Seem like your far clipping plane is causing this. What is it's current value? Change it and see.

Comment: Current value of the near/far planes is is 1-5000.  If I change the far plan a little (e.g., 5050) it makes no difference.  A lot (20,000, but keeping a sphere radius of 5,000) it does: but I don't want to leave it like that since there'll be a massive waste of precision for the visible objects.  The sphere's radius is definitely less than the clip distance anyway... so why would it affect it?

Comment: So it IS the far clipping plane, we now know that much. :) Now, are you keeping the sky sphere a constant distance from the camera? What is this distance?

Comment: "outVS.posH = mul(float4(posL, 1.0f), g_mWorldViewProj).xyzw; // Always on the far plane" <- this line looks suspect to me

Comment: What's suspect about that line?  The distance is that it's translated to be centred around the camera, and it has a fixed radius.

Comment: @ananthonline: Also, changing its radius to be 0.5 of the near/far distance still produces artefacts.  That's well within the distance that should draw correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is certainly caused by far plane clipping. If changing the sphere's radius a bit doesn't help, then the sphere's position may be wrong...

Make sure you're properly initializing `g_vecEyePos` constant (maybe you've mispelled it in one of the DirectX SetShaderConstant functions?).

Also, if you've included the translation to the eye's position in the world matrix of `g_mWorldViewProj`, you shouldn't do `posL += g_vecEyePos;` in your VS, because it causes a vertex to be moved twice the eye's position.

In other words you should choose one of these options:

1. `g_mWorldViewProj = mCamView * mCamProj;` and `posL += g_vecEyePos;`
2. `g_mWorldViewProj = MatrixTranslation(g_vecEyePos) * mCamView * mCamProj;`

Comment: Btw, I think the sphere's radius should be `const float fRadius = GetScene().GetFarPlane();`, that's the distance from the eye to the far plane.

Comment: Neither of these worked - that is, both resulted in a black background, with no visible polygons at all.  I 'solved' it by adding a line `outVS.posH.w *= 1.01;` - seems very suspect to me, but it works.